# How are AOSP compiled .img stores in phone flash?

Tags: fastboot, rom, aosp

There are the contents of a Xiaomi image for some phone that I downloaded. It is a fastboot image. I think that it means that it can be flashed by fastboot.

```
├── AP
│   ├── APDB_MT6768_S01__W2006
│   └── APDB_MT6768_S01__W2006_ENUM
├── BP
│   ├── DbgInfo_LR12A.R3.MP_HUAQIN_Q0MP1_MT6769_SP_MOLY_LR12A_R3_MP_V98_P75_2020_12_11_16_34_1_ulwctg_n
│   ├── MDDB_InfoCustomAppSrcP_MT6768_S00_MOLY_LR12A_R3_MP_V98_P75_1_ulwctg_n.EDB
│   ├── MDDB.META_MT6768_S00_MOLY_LR12A_R3_MP_V98_P75_1_ulwctg_n.EDB
│   └── MDDB.META.ODB_MT6768_S00_MOLY_LR12A_R3_MP_V98_P75_1_ulwctg_n.XML.GZ
├── BP_IN
├── CheckSum_Gen
├── check_sum.sh
├── flash_all.bat
├── flash_all_except_data_storage.bat
├── flash_all_except_data_storage.sh
├── flash_all_lock.bat
├── flash_all_lock.sh
├── flash_all.sh
├── flash_gen_crc_list.py
├── flash_gen_md5_list.py
├── flash_gen_resparsecount
├── hat_extract.py
├── hat_flash.sh
├── images
│   ├── boot.img
│   ├── cache.img
│   ├── Checksum.ini
│   ├── crclist.txt
│   ├── cust.img
│   ├── dtbo.img
│   ├── exaid.img
│   ├── gsort.img
│   ├── lk.img
│   ├── logo.bin
│   ├── md1img.img
│   ├── MT6768_Android_scatter.txt
│   ├── oem_misc1.img
│   ├── preloader_merlin.bin
│   ├── recovery.img
│   ├── scp.img
│   ├── sparsecrclist.txt
│   ├── spmfw.img
│   ├── sspm.img
│   ├── super.img
│   ├── tee.img
│   ├── userdata.img
│   ├── vbmeta.img
│   ├── vbmeta_system.img
│   └── vbmeta_vendor.img
├── libflashtoolEx.so
├── libflashtool.so
├── libflashtool.v1.so
├── Log
│   └── ADPT_20201218-033445_0.log
├── md5sum.xml
└── misc.txt
```

I never compiled Android. I'm gonna buy an SSD just for that, but meanwhile I'm trying to understand the output of the AOSP project when I build everything.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450678/how-is-the-aosp-project-built/65527251#65527251 which explains how some .img are built. For example, this is how system.img is built: [system.img](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/Makefile;l=2577;drc=d21e7dc8334528247ae47ddb7a0f7fb52f387576)

Looking at the structure of the ROM above, I guess the only things produced by AOSP are the .img. I guess the `flash_all.sh` is an script that flashes all the images to the flash memory.

How are those images stored in the flash memory? How does fastboot knows where to place each .img?

If we look at the `flash_all.sh`:

```
fastboot $* flash cache `dirname $0`/images/cache.img
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo "Flash cache error"; exit 1; fi
fastboot $* flash recovery `dirname $0`/images/recovery.img
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo "Flash recovery error"; exit 1; fi
fastboot $* flash boot `dirname $0`/images/boot.img
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo "Flash boot error"; exit 1; fi
```

it passes a different name for each .img. Maybe there's a 'fastboot server' on the phone that knows where to place each image?

Comment: partitions have labels. kernel creates symlinks you can show *'ls -d $(find /dev/block -name by-name)/\*'* in adb shell. actually the [fastboot commands](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands) are very basic. preloader decide which boot mode and will execute fastboot program from `lk` partition (i believe it's already the 3rd state in boot chain) https://www.lieberbiber.de/2015/07/04/mediatek-details-partitions-and-preloader. scatter file is for [SP Flash Tool](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool) in download mode (not fastboot)

Comment: please note that super is actually three partitions in one (system vendor product) and fastboot can not handle this. therefore fastboot is splitted in two stages and the second stage is executed from somewhere different https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/fastbootd